# Grant access to a single Google Adwords campaign

Tags: google-ads

We have a Google Adwords account that has multiple campaigns active on it.  One of our clients has requested to view its campaign, run reports, etc.  Is it possible to grant access to this single campaign for this single customer on our Adwords account?

Granting access to the entire Adwords account (which contains data for all of our clients) is probably not the best approach! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion each client should have it's own account within an MCC. If you have 1 campaign per client in 1 account i'd suggest researching about the MCC and splitting your client campaigns out into individual accounts. Unfortunately you will not be able to grant access for individual campaigns.

If you are using an MCC you will be able to grant read only access (or different levels of access) for your client for that particular account.

It will also mean that you will be able to create and optimise multiple campaigns at ease for individual clients and will allow for better and more efficient reporting.